# Is it possible to force Qt to use ANGLE when cross compiling from Linux to Windows?

Tags: qt, go, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html

> For Qt Quick 2 to work, a graphics driver that provides OpenGL 2.1 or
>   higher is required. The default driver from Windows is OpenGL 1.1.

```
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 15.63 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 512x1024
qt.scenegraph.general: R/G/B/A Buffers:    8 8 8 8
qt.scenegraph.general: Depth Buffer:       32
qt.scenegraph.general: Stencil Buffer:     8
qt.scenegraph.general: Samples:            -1
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VENDOR:          Microsoft Corporation
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_RENDERER:        GDI Generic
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VERSION:         1.1.0
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_EXTENSIONS:      GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_paletted_texture
qt.scenegraph.general: Max Texture Size:  1024
qt.scenegraph.general: Debug context:     false
```

Due to this problem, my app is crashing on Windows.

My co-worker tried to build it on Windows and it works because it fall back to [ANGLE](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/master/README.md):

```
qt.scenegraph.general: windows render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 15.63 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 512x1024
qt.scenegraph.general: R/G/B/A Buffers:    8 8 8 8
qt.scenegraph.general: Depth Buffer:       24
qt.scenegraph.general: Stencil Buffer:     8
qt.scenegraph.general: Samples:            0
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VENDOR:          Google Inc.
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_RENDERER:        ANGLE (Microsoft Basic Render Driver Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VERSION:         OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.8613f4946861)
```

The thing is we are building from Linux using `threcipe/qt:windows_64_shared` image: https://github.com/therecipe/qt/wiki/Deploying-Linux-to-Windows-64-bit-Shared

I tried something like this:

- `export QT_OPENGL=angle` when building
- copy `D3Dcompiler_47.dll`, `libEGL.dll`, `libGLESV2.dll`, and `opengl32sw.dll` to the app folder

but the app hangs when starting. There is no logs in console even with `QT_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true`.

Is it possible to force Qt to use `ANGLE` when building on Linux? If yes, how?